# How to email bold text from android application?

Tags: android

I am using this code for mailing from android application.

```
GmailSender sender = new GmailSender("android.tech1q2@gmail.com","password");
sender.sendMail("Thank you  state",
              "<u>Jignesh</u><b>Jignesh</b>",
              "android.tech1q2@gmail.com",
              "jansodariya@gmail.com");
```

but I am not getting words underline and bold then what should I do for this please help me
I want to send mail as Html.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you send your mail as HTML ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
sender.sendMail("Thank you  state"
              ,Html.fromHtml("<u>Jignesh</u><b>Jignesh</b>"),
              "android.tech1q2@gmail.com"
              "jansodariya@gmail.com"));
```

Comment: html.fromhtml method not accepting more than 1 argument..so another way>

Comment: check now. You can also add Html.fromHtml() for each String you want to show as HTML